# Is there a way to fire webjob without using a queue or blob storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I have created a webjob which i want to be triggered only manually and not using a queue or blob. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: it is not broad. it is right to the point.

Comment: I agree, it might be a beginner's question but it is specific and the answer is clear.

Comment: @camelCase - One of the areas of confusion about WebJobs that I see today (which I thin is related to the newness of the feature) is that WebJobs exist in two forms: the WebJobs SDK and manually via the WebJobs interface in the portal.  The hooks into Azure Storage (like the queues and blobs you referred to) are primarily a part of the WebJobs SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you create an On Demand Task then you use the portal to run it.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateOnDemand